# Failing to upload a copied(then renamed) android project back onto Github from Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github

I duplicated a local copy of an Android project on my PC from File Explorer. This project was already uploaded onto GitHub successfully. I believe I followed the steps to rename/refactor the copy to a new name. The package name and app name all display the new name I want.

However, when I attempt to share it back on GitHub, it says it already exists (displaying the previous app name).
Not sure how to get my local, renamed version back on Github as a new project and not overwriting the previously named version.

Answer (score 0):

find a hidden folder inside your project, having name `.git` delete it and then share your project to github.

There is config file inside `.git` folder, may be that having address of your remote git project.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to delete the .git folder: that would lose the history!

Simply create an empty GitHub repo, and on your local copy, do

```
cd /path/to/local/copy
git remote set-url origin /url/new/empty/github/repo
git push --mirror
```

You don't have to rename the parent folder of your local copy, or rename anything: just make sure its default remote upstream repo "`origin`" references now *your* GitHub repo.